# C program crashes when trying to refer to struct array

Tags: c, arrays, windows, struct, crash

I'm trying to make a simple database program, but when I get to this line

```
int idSearch(product* itens, int id) {
    int i = 0;
    for(i; i < size; i++) {
        if(itens[i].id == id) //<=== This line
            return i;
    }
    return ITEM_NOT_FOUND;
}
```

the program stops responding.
size is set as a global variable in the begining of the program

```
FILE* flog;
FILE* db;
FILE* sizef;
int size = 100;
```

this function is called by

```
void newProduct(product* itens, char name[64], int id, float price) {
    int pos = idSearch(itens, 0);

    if(idSearch(itens, id) != ITEM_NOT_FOUND) {
        printf("Erro, o produto ja existe");
        return;
    }...
```

items is defined as

```
itens = (product*) calloc(sizeof(product), size);
```

and product is a `struct` defined as such

```
typedef struct{
    char    name[64];
    int     id;
    float   price;
    int     amount;
} product;
```

Firstly I thought the problem was that I was not using the `->` operator, but when I tried the compiler says its not right.

I'm using Code::Blocks with GCC compiler on a Windows 7 x64

**EDIT: the whole code can be found here: http://hastebin.com/atulajubar.tex

Hope to hear answers soon, Thanks in advance

Comment: Where is `size` defined in your first block of code? And what is it defined to?

Comment: `size` is defined as a global variable that was set to 100 in the main function. It was initialized as 0 though

Comment: Show the definition of `itens` ? That is, from where you passed it to `newProduct` ?

Comment: It's very difficult to tell from your code sample what the value is at the point of this function. Also, how was `itens` allocated? What size?

Comment: the value of i when the program stops is 0, I tested with a simple `printf` before the `if`

Comment: First of all do not typecast product. Second do not use calloc. Use malloc instead. 3rd is a question - what compiler are you using?

Comment: Ok we know how but we dont know WHERE do you allocate the space in your code.

Comment: @Edenia: why is it not OK to use `calloc()` in your view?  It has some advantages and is certainly not incorrect here.  Kasama: do you check that `calloc()` was successful? Do you change `size` after the `calloc()`?

Comment: It is customary to pass the magnitude of one's array to any function that needs it. Don't rely on a global. Both `newProduct` and `idSearch` should have the proper size passed as an additional parameter. As written it is simply not possible to answer your question as you've given no reproducible steps, so guesses and speculation are the best you can hope for (and doesn't make for a good question, btw). My advise. lose the global `size` make it local  to the creator of your array, and pass it along with the array base address as a param where needed. (and `calloc` is fine if used right).

Comment: @Edenia: I do allocate `itens` right at the start of the main function, I could post the whole program, but I'm trying to keep it simple and not messy.

Comment: Im not saying its not incorrect.. but calloc is influented from free/realloc and.. apparently he is not showing the full code here. I bet there is a free somewhere?. Anyway.. try to initialize the structure.
right after you declare it.
In your case you can do: 
`product itens = {.member1 = 3, .member2 = 3};` and so on
I connected your puzzle code and it does not crash for me.

Comment: @WhozCraig I will do that, my teacher always said global variables are not reliable, but i tend to forget it. the problem is not the `size` variable though, if I change it to 100 (Its value when it crashes) it does still crash

Comment: Your teacher is right. There is no warranty that the variable will have the needed storage allocated. If it continues with the crash.. try what i offered you.

Comment: @Edenia I need to read the itens array from a file, I'm doing it with a `fread(itens, sizeof(product), size, db);` after i allocate the space for it using `calloc`

Comment: @Edenia sorry, but what do you mean by reference `itens`

Comment: Nevermind if all of what are you doing is correct. You shouldn't have any native problems. But you have provided only a really small pice of one entire system.

Comment: @Edenia could I send you the whole program via pastebin or something? Would it help?

Comment: Use hastebin.com so i can check it and/or compile it on my own.

Comment: Unrealted: `!strcmp(*product, name))` isn't good in `showProductReport`. That should be `!strcmp(product, name))`. A `char` is not a `char*`. Related. You know you only allocate memory for `items` if the DB file was *not* present, right?

Comment: Didnt you got an error at line 404? (404 - Not found - what an irony)
Anyway. For me it works fine in all the road of the program. (when fixing the 1st parameter of the `strcmp`)

Comment: @WhozCraig I did get this error, but forgot to fix it. Craig, I have not realized how dumb that was until you told me what I've done. Now it works properly! Thanks a lot

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is wrong:

```
if((db = fopen(DB_PATH, RB))==NULL)
{
    if((db = fopen(DB_PATH, RWB))==NULL)
    {
        exit(1);
    }
    else
    {
        itens = (product*) calloc(sizeof(product), size);
        fwrite(itens, sizeof(product), size, db);
        rewind(db);
    }
}
fread(itens, sizeof(product), size, db);
```

If you have a DB_PATH file in the current working directory the first `fopen()` will succeed and the `items` allocation will never take place. Only if the file is *not* found, but is then *successfully* created will `items` contain a valid allocation, assuming `calloc` worked.

That `else` condition should be removed:

```
// note calloc parameter order addressed.
itens = calloc(size, sizeof(product));
if (itens == NULL)
{
    perror("Failed to allocate items.");
    exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
}

if((db = fopen(DB_PATH, RB))==NULL)
{
    if((db = fopen(DB_PATH, RWB))==NULL)
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);

    fwrite(itens, sizeof(product), size, db);
    rewind(db);
}

fread(itens, sizeof(product), size, db);
```

There is a significant amount of error checking left to handle, but this needs to be addressed regardless.

Answer (score 2):

****EDIT: You're calling [calloc()](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/calloc.html) wrong. The signature is: `void *calloc(size_t nelem, size_t elsize);`
You're giving it the size first, *then* the number of elements. Switch that around and see if your problem is resolved.**

Also, when calling (AFTER THE FIX:) `itens = (product*) calloc( size, sizeof(product) );`,
it's important to check to see that itens is not NULL after doing this. If calloc isn't able to give you back the right amount of memory, it returns a NULL pointer I believe. Check this, because if you're getting NULL back, that's your issue.

One good, easy, portable way of checking that would be:

```
if(!itens){
   fprintf(stderr, "Error! Could not allocate memory!\n");
   exit(1);
}
```

Also, as WhozCraig suggested, please make sure your code contains `#include <stdlib.h>`, a requirement of calloc() as per its man page.

Comment: I honestly doubt gcc compiled program will crash if buffer overflow.

Comment: i tried printing `i` and `size` and i got 0 and 100 respectively. Can it mean that my itens array is somehow without any allocated space?

Comment: @Kasama are you segfaulting? I would try to just print out itens[0] , [1] etc and see what result you get that way. Without a loop. If that crashes, there's your issue. Although, calloc() should be zeroing the memory. See my edit

Comment: @Kasama It more than likely means you have either freed the memory and/or are toting around an indeterminate pointer. `printf("itens=%p\n", itens);` immediately after the `calloc()` and likewise just inside your other functions *may* expose a junk pointer, but will *not* expose an incorrectly freed pointer. This app doesn't sound large. is there any chance at all you can simply post *all* the source to settle this once and for all?

Comment: @Kasama oh, and in since no on else bothered mentioning this, make sure `<stdlib.h>` is included (I will cackle big-time if that solves your issue, btw).

Comment: @Kasama see my edit again. You were/are calling calloc() with the wrong arguments - this is most likely at least one of your issues.

Comment: @Ricky Mutschlechner
Yep. Thats why i suggested malloc. But noone seem'd to notice anything wrong with that calloc :D

Comment: Now when we see from his full code. He is using `stdlib.h`

Comment: @RickyMutschlechner Thanks, didn't realize that, but even with calloc right it still crashes

Comment: @Kasama in your practice with gcc i will advice you to look foward on the crashes. Because that means "something is wrong with your code" ..with your `calloc` syntax mistake.. you wouldn't notice the error, you could ruin your entire program most likely. But since calloc is dependable.. crash is also possible.

Comment: @RickyMutschlechner not to rain on that parade, but the order of parameters submitted to calloc makes no difference on nearly all implementations (it *can* make a difference on segmented architectures micro controllers, and the like, but the OP has already state such is not the case). In the end its simply `x * y` established as the allocated region. And `x * y == y * x`. Its a good catch, but I'll be shocked if it contributes to the actual problem.

Comment: @WhozCraig not aways the problem is just one.. the first one - chain reaction. Now when we have the full code, we can identify the code.

Comment: @WhozCraig I see your point, however, doesn't gcc do some weirdness with padding and whatnot? I feel like it would not work properly somehow unless you do it the right way. Not positive.

Comment: @RickyMutschlechner not really. The structure padding will be accounted for in one of the two presented terms, which one depending on the proper or improper call. So long as the two values are presented correctly, it will ultimately make no difference on most implementations. It violates the standard to call it incorrectly, however, and you're quite correct in pointing that out. On some platforms (such as a selector-array situation), it is conceivable a boundary inaccuracy on elements could cause a problem. Order *is* important, but usually makes no difference (sharp eye in noticing, btw).